# What is the proper way of testing a component in Vue with API calls?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a problem understand testing Vue components. In the [component testing docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/testing.html#component-testing), it says:

> Component tests should focus on the component's public interfaces
> rather than internal implementation details. For most components, the
> public interface is limited to: events emitted, props, and slots. When
> testing, remember to test what a component does, not how it does it.

Say you have a Form Component:

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    Email: <input type="text" data-test="email" v-model="user.email" /> <br />
    First: <input type="text" data-test="first" v-model="user.first" /> <br />
    Last: <input type="text" data-test="last" v-model="user.last" /> <br />
    <button type="submit">Create User</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { createUser } from '@/api'
import { notify } from '@/helpers'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    user: {
      email: '',
      first: '',
      last: ''
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      try {
        const result = await createUser(this.user)
        notify.success({
          message: 'Success'
        })
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
      } catch {
        notify.error({
          message: 'Error occurred'
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here's how I test it:

```js
import router from '@/router';
import * as fetchers from '@/api'
import { notify } from '@/helpers'
import fp from 'flush-promises'

test('should save car details', async () => {
  const successSpy = jest.spyOn(notify, 'success')
  const createUserSpy = jest.spyOn(fetchers, 'createUser')
  const routerPushSpy = jest.spyOn(router, 'push')

  const wrapper = mount(Form)

  await wrapper.find('[data-test="email"]').setValue('test@email.com');
  await wrapper.find('[data-test="first"]').setValue('John');
  await wrapper.find('[data-test="last"]').setValue('Doe');
  await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
  await fp();

  expect(successSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    message: 'Success',
  })
  expect(createUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    email: 'test@email.com',
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe'
  });
  expect(routerPushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'Home' });
});
```

While this test works, I am not sure if this is the correct way of component testing based on Vue docs. Looks like I'm testing internal details in that test?

How should I do it?

Comment: It's unknown if `notify` is  represented in a view in this case. But isolated unit tests should mock other units (notify, fetchers, router), with only current unit (Form) being tested. So it's ok to assert their calls because there is no  behaviour that could be tested. It's unknown if this was done here, the use of flush-promises suggests that at least a request was mocked

Comment: Notify uses https://buefy.org/documentation/toast programmatically underneath and also have its own unit test. But here I am spying on it again just to see if it worked

Comment: It's helpful to spy things to get extra feedback on possible causes of failures, but here it should be mocked. The question is labeled with unit testing. Unit tests are to test single units. Not mocking them results in testing multiple units together, i.e. integration test.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask, that's very helpful! Do you also think spying on router there is needed? The way it works is that on success, it will redirect to home page.

Comment: Yes, but a router is the first thing that needs to be mocked. It results in global side effects that may break test isolation